# Anonymize SQL Code

Tags: support, feature-request

Once a user of DatabaseAdministrators told me a webservice or something similar that can help to make SQL Code obfuscated so that meaningful/distinctive fields / column names / variables are anonymized and won't allow any conclusions to companies or products. I need this to post code into questions on the main site.

Unfortunately I forgot and can't find this specific comment any more.

Does anyone know where to find this?
Might this not be a super feature on the site itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Sentry [Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) (PE) can anonymize queries:

[image]

There are limits though, and you will need to be careful to ensure that the anonymized code is still useful in the context of your question. I don't think PE will fully anonymize complex scripts with extensive DDL, for example. Other people might be able to make suggestions for that.

Please make sure you have the most recent version of PE (there were more limitations in early versions of the feature). That said, you can also just search and replace in the output file (it's just XML) if you only need to hide table name patterns or other things without obfuscating everything.

Some questions will require more than that, which is probably a sign that you need to engage a consultant rather than asking a Q & A community.